# Default page in Metro + VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make a Metro app using VS11 on Windows 8 CP using Visual Basic. Fo some reason, the usual "Default object" setting in the settings for the application is grayed out. How exactly are you supposed to set the default form now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh look, I managed to find my own answer. In the App.xaml.vb file, there is this line:

```
rootFrame.Navigate(GetType(BlankPage))
```

Set that variable in the brackets to the page you want to open by default.